# Getting error in receiving push notification using apple push notification service in ios

Tags: ios5, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I have developed a application that uses appcelerator cloud service and APN everything working fine I was able to register the device for push notification and even able to successfully send notification but in the receiving path of the notification I am getting error like `UILocalNotification keyed archive array contains invalid classes: *** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver decodeObjectForKey:]: data to unarchive contains class (NSDecimalNumberPlaceholder) which has not been allowed. Ignoring.`

I am not able to trace what this error try to say please help me out.

Thanks 
Pushpa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just ran into this as well. It seemed to consistently happen for me when you set the badge in the APNS payload to a negative number. See if this goes away if you add a check on your server to make sure the badge is always set to >=0.

Hope that helps.

Cheers,
Ashu